# Botão Selecionar Bloco/Página nas Propriedades do Widget não aparece

Tags: magento, back-end, widget

boa tarde!

Já aconteceu algo assim com vocês?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Host novinho, da GoDaddy. Instalação 0km...

Quando vou criar um widget, depois de selecionar o tipo e template, não consigo selecionar Bloco e Pagina CMS, Produto, ou Categoria... o botão simplesmente não aparece.

Instalei inicialmente a versão 1.9.2.2, depois tentei com a 1.9.1, e a 1.9.0 e nada. Com todas as versões acontece o mesmo.

Fiz um teste e importei a instalação de um outro site através do cPanel da GoDaddy e esse veio perfeito. A versão desta loja é 1.8.1.1.

Não sei mais o que fazer, alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Abraço e obrigado desde já!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depois de muitos testes acabei descobrindo que o problema era com o tema. Eu estava tentando com o template default, mas o customizado já estava no servidor e de algum forma estava interferindo.